# How load and access yii2 modules dynamically in Frontend?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have module stored in `/common/modules/gopay/GopayModule.php` and I am dynamically loading it via `Yii::$app->setModule('gopayModule', ['class' => '\common\modules\gopay\GopayModule']);` in CommonController which is child of yii\web\Controller and parent of all my FE and BE controllers.

I did not put any configuration for module into config files as Im loading it dynamically.

How can I access this module from frontend, so that it creates application based on FE config and so on? What decides which part of Yii2, BE or FE should be called when calling module route? Traditional routes as `/index.php?r=gopayModule/default/index` or `/gopayModule/default/index` are not working even when url manager is none.

thx :)

Answer (score 1):

:D easy peasy, I was setting module late, I changed code to load/set module in my CommonRequest class init() method and everything working like a charm, so logically I need to load module before UrlManager is processing URL ;-)